# Self hosted HTTPS WCF service breaks IIS site using SSL

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl, self-hosting

I've got a self-hosted service (Windows Service) running on my server.  When it starts however, it seems to block an existing SSL site set up in IIS.  Meaning, when the service is not running, my SSL site works normally.  When the service IS running, my site stops working and responds with an "Endpoint not found" error.  It's almost like the service is grabbing the call to the site before IIS can respond itself.

Some info:
The self hosted services and the IIS site are set to different IPs, and different SSL certificates.  They basically have no overlap aside from residing on the same server.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Try running each site under its own application pool

Comment: The self hosted service isn't running in IIS, it's not in an application pool, it's in an entirely different process, so, effectively, they are already in in different pools.

Comment: Ohhk missed that part :) I would suggest you use a network capture tool like Fiddler or Wireshark to explore why the calls to your site are failing

Comment: The issue is with how the server routes the call, fiddler won't tell me anything useful in this case.

Comment: I guess your services sits on the same port - try to expose the self hosted service on different port and it should work.

Comment: Yes, but the entire point is to expose it on port 443.